# bitset<32> size of 8 bytes?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bit

I am just confused about exact size of a bitset<32> element.

As the [document](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/size/) for `std::bitset::size` says:

> Returns the number of bits in the bitset.

As the [document](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) of `sizeof` says

> Returns size in bytes of the object representation of type.

So I tried to use the two functions in the following program

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    unsigned char a = 0; // a = 5(00000101)
    std::bitset<32> x(a);

    cout << sizeof(x) << endl;
    cout << x.size() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
8 
32
```

Why doesn't the `sizeof(x)` return 4? As 32 bits should be equal to 4 bytes, instead of 8?

Comment: `sizeof()` gives you the space actually needed in memory. On a 64 bit machine architecture it would be quite likely that a `std::bitset<32>` is stored using an underlying `uint64_t` instead of a `uint32_t`.

Comment: got it. thanks! I also find this link with similar ideas helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12459563/what-is-the-size-of-bitset-in-c